# Android issue with published version to google play

Tags: codenameone

New Android update, I'm seeing the following warnings please help if anyone know what can be done[image]

androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0
This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Consider upgrading to a newer version (1.0.1 - 1.0.2, 1.1.0-alpha02+).

androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0
This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Consider upgrading to a newer version (1.1.0+).